# Changing bibliography styles locally

Tags: tables, bibliographies

Is it possible to change the bibliography style locally in a document from author-year to numbered citation.

I have used Apalike in the thesis that I am writing now, but there are two tables which contain a lot of references. Thus, it would be handy to have numbered citations in the table.

for instance:

```
% Preamble:
\documentclass[global, referee]{svjour}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{subfig} 
%-----------------%---------------------------------------------------%-----------------%
\begin{document}
%-----------------%---------------------------------------------------%-----------------%
\begin{abstract}
This is abstract

%-----------------%---------------------------------------------------%-----------------%
\section{Introduction}
this is introduction
%-----------------%---------------------------------------------------%-----------------%
%begin environment
%here change the bibliography style to a numbered citation bibliography style for e.g. ieeetr%

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \caption{test table}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \toprule
    {Compound} & {\% variance (R$^2$)} \\
    \midrule
    A & 7.1 \citep{Franek2, Eagle}\\            \rule{0cm}{0.50cm}
    B & 7.4 \citep{Franek2, Eagle, Taylor}\\                \rule{0cm}{0.50cm}
    C & 6.0 \citep{Franek2, Eagle, Taylor} \\           \rule{0cm}{0.50cm}
    D & 6.8 \citep{Franek2, Eagle, Taylor, Carvalhal}\\     \rule{0cm}{0.50cm}
    E & 5.2 \\          
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tableauc}%
\end{table}%

%end environment
%-----------------%---------------------------------------------------%-----------------%
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To what would these numbered references point?  Would there be a separate bibliography?  Although footnotes in tables -- tablenotes, if you will -- are often discouraged (rightly or wrongly), it might be a reasonable compromise in this case.

Comment: I do not want to create a separate bibliography for the table. If I have 20 references in table: footnotes will cover half of my page which is not acceptable.

Comment: Then what purpose would a numbered system serve in what is otherwise an author-year system?  Surely, either they are all author-year, or none are....

Comment: Convenience and readability of the table. Otherwise, for e.g. in a cell, I would see a value with 5 references. for e.g. 20- 25 % (Doe et al, Smith et al, Jane et al.) If I have a big table, you can imagine what would happen.

Comment: I understand that.  I mean: the numbered bibliography items have to be somewhere else --- where would that be? and how would it (not) relate to the regular bibliography?  You are not providing much information about how everything should fit together.

Comment: Also: 'table' notes usually are / can be put at the end of the table, sort of like 'table endnotes'.

Comment: Sorry about that. I tried to put my explanation in kind of code. I hope it helps. I can try with notes too - but again, notes would cover a lot of space. I have like 30 references, which will certainly take a lot of space on the page too.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12551/discussion-between-abhishek-and-jon)

Comment: Your example code isn't compilable as shown -- should you be loading the `natbib` package as well? Have you tried loading the `natbib` package with the option `numbers`?

Comment: yes. it is a non-working example to explain better my question.